# Help required: zip files streaming

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, client-server

i have problem in sending zip file in network.. all other formats i am able to send except .zip..

i tried a lot i dont no how to do this.. the code i have written at client side to upload file, this is suggested by microsoft here is  the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446517.aspx)

i am able to create zip file, if i try to open it says corrupted..size of the file also varying lot.

here is code

```
  public void UploadFile(string localFile, string uploadUrl)
    {

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uploadUrl);

        req.Method = "PUT";
        req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;

        // Retrieve request stream and wrap in StreamWriter
        Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();
        StreamWriter wrtr = new StreamWriter(reqStream);

        // Open the local file


        Stream Stream = File.Open(localFile, FileMode.Open);

        // loop through the local file reading each line 
        //  and writing to the request stream buffer 

        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = Stream.Read(buff, 0,1024)) > 0)
        {
            wrtr.Write(buff);
        }



        Stream.Close();
        wrtr.Close();

        try
        {
            req.GetResponse();
        }
        catch(Exception ee)
        {

        }

        reqStream.Close();
```

please help me...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you're using a StreamWriter, which is a TextWriter, designed for *text* data, not binary files like zip files.

Additionally there's the problem Jacob mentioned, and also the fact that you're not closing the request stream until after you've received the response - although that won't make any difference because the `StreamWriter` will close it first.

Here's the fixed code, changed to use `using` statements (to avoid leaving streams open), a simpler call to the `File` class, and more meaningful names (IMO).

```
using (Stream output = req.GetRequestStream())
using (Stream input = File.OpenRead(localFile))
{
    // loop through the local file reading each line 
    //  and writing to the request stream buffer 

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0)
    {
        output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
```

Note that you can easily extract the while loop into a helper method:

```
public static void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
{
    // loop through the local file reading each line 
    //  and writing to the request stream buffer 

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0)
    {
        output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
```

to be used from other places, leaving just:

```
using (Stream output = req.GetRequestStream())
using (Stream input = File.OpenRead(localFile))
{
    CopyStream(input, output);
}
```