# Export DataSet to Multiple Excel Sheets and download into a zip file using asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Hi how to Export DataSet to Multiple Excel Sheets and download those file into a zip in C# asp.net?

Answer (score 1):

This has already been well covered on Stack Overflow.
First of all, to create your Excel spreadsheets, check this previous post:

- [Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c)

Next to zip the files, check these excellent answers:

- [How to zip multiple files using only .net api in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243929/how-to-zip-multiple-files-using-only-net-api-in-c)
- [C# .net code for zipping a file using PKZIP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202772/c-net-code-for-zipping-a-file-using-pkzip)
- [Sample C# .net code for zipping a file using 7zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203701/sample-c-net-code-for-zipping-a-file-using-7zip)
- [more potential answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=zip+files+[c%23])

If you want to automatically stream it back to the user, then try these answers:

- [Create Zip file from stream and download it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266204/create-zip-file-from-stream-and-download-it)
- [Help required: zip files streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768713/help-required-zip-files-streaming)
- [How do you stream a zip file from the click of an image button in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619643/how-do-you-stream-a-zip-file-from-the-click-of-an-image-button-in-asp-net)
- [ASP.NET Download All Files as Zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670263/asp-net-download-all-files-as-zip)

Answer (score 0):

[NPoi](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) for export and [DotNetZip Library](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) for ziping it.

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub CopySheet()
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
        Dim dt As String
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
        Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\EXCEL\From.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"
        Dim oledbConn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(connString)
        Try
            oledbConn.Open()
            For i = 0 To 1
                If i = 0 Then
                    cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", oledbConn)
                    dt = "Sheet3"
                Else
                    cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet2$]", oledbConn)
                    dt = "Sheet4"
                End If
                Dim oleda As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
                oleda.SelectCommand = cmd
                oleda.Fill(ds, dt)
            Next

```
        ExportDatasetToExcel(ds, "dd")
    Catch
    Finally
        oledbConn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub ExportDatasetToExcel(ByVal ds As DataSet, ByVal strExcelFile As String)

    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\EXCEL\To.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"))
    conn.Open()
    Dim strTableQ(ds.Tables.Count) As String
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    'making table query
    For i = 0 To ds.Tables.Count - 1
        strTableQ(i) = "CREATE TABLE [" & ds.Tables(i).TableName & "]("
        Dim j As Integer = 0
        For j = 0 To ds.Tables(i).Columns.Count - 1
            Dim dCol As DataColumn
            dCol = ds.Tables(i).Columns(j)
            strTableQ(i) &= " [" & dCol.ColumnName & "] varchar(255) , "
        Next
        strTableQ(i) = strTableQ(i).Substring(0, strTableQ(i).Length - 2)
        strTableQ(i) &= ")"
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(strTableQ(i), conn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
    'making insert query
    Dim strInsertQ(ds.Tables.Count - 1) As String
    For i = 0 To ds.Tables.Count - 1
        strInsertQ(i) = "Insert Into " & ds.Tables(i).TableName & " Values ("
        For k As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(i).Columns.Count - 1
            strInsertQ(i) &= "@" & ds.Tables(i).Columns(k).ColumnName & " , "
        Next
        strInsertQ(i) = strInsertQ(i).Substring(0, strInsertQ(i).Length - 2)
        strInsertQ(i) &= ")"
    Next
    'Now inserting data
    For i = 0 To ds.Tables.Count - 1
        For j As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(i).Rows.Count - 1
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(strInsertQ(i), conn)
            For k As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(i).Columns.Count - 1
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" & ds.Tables(i).Columns(k).ColumnName.ToString(), ds.Tables(i).Rows(j)(k).ToString())
            Next
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()
        Next
    Next

    conn.Close()
End Sub
```